# How to interpolate data using the pandas's reindex method 'ffill'?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, reindex

I have been reading Wes McKinney's book Python for Data Science. In the fifth chapter of the book-- an introduction to pandas-- there is a subsection regarding reindexing. The author uses pandas's reindex method to add new rows to a DataFrame object; the method 'ffill' is used to forward interpolate the missing data.
Although I tried to implement the same code, neither are new rows being created nor is data being interpolated. What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame,Series

data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10,10))
df = DataFrame(data,index = [i for i in range(0,20,2)])
a = df[0]
a.reindex(range(20),method='ffill')
print a
```

I expect new odd-numbered row indices to be created and forward filled with data, but the extracted Seies object 'a' is not being altered at all.

Here is the actual result:

```
data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10,10))...
0     43
2     47
4     41
6     76
8     78
10     9
12    13
14    23
16    40
18    87
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Here is the expected result:

```
data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10,10))...
0     43
1     43
2     47
3     47
.
.
.
18    87
19    87
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All working nice, only is necessary assign output back to variable `a`, because `reindex` not working inplace:

```
np.random.seed(1)
data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10,10))
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index = [i for i in range(0,20,2)])
a = df[0]
a = a.reindex(range(20),method='ffill')
print (a)
0     37
1     37
2     76
3     76
4     29
5     29
6      9
7      9
8      8
9      8
10    49
11    49
12    41
13    41
14    25
15    25
16     8
17     8
18    74
19    74
Name: 0, dtype: int32
```